# Asus laptop beeps when I walk away

Tags: laptop, asus-laptop

The sound is the same as the one you hear when you plug in and unplug a USB device. It beeps when I approach the laptop and leave it and also sometimes when I move in front of it. This is an ASUS, model G73JH.

Comment: Possibly there's some software involved doing facial recognition on the webcam to enable/disable functionality of the machine if a user isn't present?  I know new ThinkPads have an app that'll lock the machine down if you walk away.

Comment: Sounds like you have it set for puppy emulation mode.  :-)

Answer (score 5):

What you are experiencing is the ASUS SmartLogon feature. It is a facial recognition feature that logs in for you and logs out automatically.

Here is the link to the ASUS SmartLogon user guide:

> ftp://ftp.asus.com.tw/pub/asus/nb/U6/ASUS_SmartLogon_UserGuide_VT_EN_V1.pdf

Comment: Looks like I'm a good guesser.

Comment: I can't believe the folks at Asus did know about this.  The strange thing is that when I disconnected my logitech trackman wheel mouse the sound stops.  Also when I replace that mouse with a another similar mouse I have no beeps.